# Javascript date string to angular ng-moment variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I have a javascript string in the following format:

```
2016-06-22T14:47:29.689358
```

How would I use `ng-moment` to parse the string into a moment object and then format it inside my view?

https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Pseudocode:

```js
$scope.time = "2016-06-22T14:47:29.689358";
```

```html
<span am-time-ago="time | amParse:'YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm:ss'"></span>
```

It seems like time needs to be converted into a Date object before it is passed to `ng-moment`.

Comment: where does the date string `2016-06-22T14:47:29.689358` come from?

Comment: @adolfosrs From a .Net web api call, returned as json and put into an angularjs object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a date at all, and in fact you shouldn't use the date object's parser as it behaves in odd ways. You just have the wrong format specified for the date you have.

```
<span am-time-ago="time | amParse:'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS'"></span>
```

That should be all you need.

For more information about why dates parse unreliably, you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874178/moment-js-timezone-inconsistency).

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the [documentation](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) you can go with

**amFromUnix filter**: Converts a unix-timestamp (seconds since 1/1/1970) into a moment object. Example:

```
<span am-time-ago="message.unixTime | amFromUnix">
```

To get the unixTime from your date string just go with the following:

```
var unixTime  = new Date("2016-06-22T14:47:29.689358").getTime();
```

Comment: so i'd have to do pre-processing in my controller prior to using moment to format the date for me, correct?  There is no way to bypass the pre-processing?

Comment: @TWilly what do you mean by pre-processing? in your case you just go with `$scope.time = new Date("2016-06-22T14:47:29.689358").getTime()`

Comment: @TWilly yes, you will need to create a date object.

Comment: This code will not work correctly across browsers. Run it in chrome on a computer in US Central time and you will get the timestamp 1466606849689, run it in firefox and you will get 1466624849689. Be very careful of the date object's parser.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like from it just wants a moment object.

```
$scope.time = moment("2016-06-22T14:47:29.689358");
```